# django confirm password validator

Tags: django, validation

I have a profile settings page where users can change their password and they have to confirm it if they do. I cannot make this a required field, since they dont HAVE to change the password. Is there an example to validate the confirm password IF the password field is not empty? And then to check if they are equal? I was not able to find any such example...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the following to your form's `clean` method:

```
def clean(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if password1 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

    return self.cleaned_data
```

**EDIT**

The validation error message above will go into `non_field_errors`. You didn't specify what error message is showing on each password field, but based on context, I would imagine it's a "This field is required" message. If that's the case, make sure that your form fields have `required=False` when you define them, or if you're working with a form subclass (and can't edit the actual form fields) you can override the `__init__` method of the form:

```
class MyForm(SomeOtherForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['password1'].required = False
        self.fields['password2'].required = False
```

Comment: Thanks! i actually just found it before your edit. For anybody else's reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: I think you actually want `if password1 and password1 != password2:` otherwise entering a password in `password1` and nothing in `password2` will not cause a validation error (assuming you have `required=False` on both fields, as is likely for a 'change password' form)

Comment: @Anentropic: good catch. I think I originally just copied that over from a registration form, where both fields were actually required.

Comment: Is password2 a part of the user model or is it exclusively defined in the forms?

Comment: I have exclusively defined `verify_password` field in the form as follows:
`verify_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())`
I can't get it to work.