# Password validation/matching not working in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have used the following two methods on login page but Django let users to register themselves with **different passwords** and is not showing the `ValidationError`.

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth import (
        authenticate,
        get_user_model,
    )

User = get_user_model()

    class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password')
        password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'email',
                'username',
                'password',
                'password2',
            ]
```

---

**method no.1:**

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).clean()

    password = cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = cleaned_data.get('password_confirm ')

    if password and password2:
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The two password fields must match.")
    return cleaned_data
```

**method no.2:**

```
    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password and password2 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords must match')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

> FYI using django 1.10 and python 3.4

Comment: can you print the `password and password2`

Comment: password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

Why not

password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)

Comment: @AgamBanga `password` is printing but `password2` is showing `None`

Comment: @Exprator new to django so trying things.

Comment: Use method 1 and change the field name to password2 where you have used 'password_confirm '. It will work as you want.

Comment: Thanks @Exprator it worked. Could you please guide me on my another question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762694/how-to-add-post-content-reading-time-in-a-django-blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762694/how-to-add-post-content-reading-time-in-a-django-blog)

Answer (score 0):

You have several logic errors here.

In your first snippet, you try and get `password_confirm` instead of `password2`.

In your second snippet, you compare the value of password2 to itself, rather than password1.

You shouldn't be checking `if password` in either snippet; that is already done by the field validation, and in any case if neither of them is supplied that is already an error.

Also you should define the `password2` field twice in your form. Why did you do that?

Comment: still not working,
I am getting my `password2` as None when printing. how can I correct it ?

Comment: took reference from another answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368947/django-confirm-password-validator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368947/django-confirm-password-validator)